# Reaching nth element of a std::list in C++

Tags: c++, list

I need to reach nth element of a list somehow. I tried the code below but it didn't work. Is there a way to get the content of nth element of a list? I can't use vectors or queues, I only can use lists. Here is my attempt :

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    list <int> mylist;
    list<int>::iterator it;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    mylist.push_back (i);

    it = mylist.begin();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(it == x)
        {
        cout<<"x found"<<endl;
        break;
        }
        advance(it,1);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `it` is of `iterator` type (iterator to given list element), you need to further de-reference to get its value.

Change

```
if (it == x)
```

to

```
if (*it == x)
    ^^^
```

Comment: Best if you explain _why_ instead of just dumping code. Again.

Answer (score 4):

The function [`std::advance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) can be used for this as follows:

```
it = mylist.begin();
std::advance(it, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the n<sup>th</sup> element, you can use `std::advance`:

```
std::list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin();
std::advance( it, n );
```

Just be sure that there are enough elements.  If you have C++11,
you can use:

```
std::list<int>::iterator it = std::next( myList.begin(), n );
```

directly.